# Backpropagation: Derivaiton of Loss Gradient

Tags: vector-analysis, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

In the book "Artifical Intelligence: A Modern Approach" from S. Russel there is a derivation of the gradient of the loss with respect to the weights w used for backpropagation on page 735.

I stumbled across the third row of the derivation, where $\Delta_k$ is inserted.
On the left side of the equation, there is still a '2', but on the right side it is gone.

Can someone explain to me what happened to that '2'?

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial Loss_k}{\partial \omega_{j,k}} &=& -2(y_k - a_k)\frac{\partial a_k}{\partial \omega_{j,k}} = -2(y_k - a_k)\frac{\partial g(in_k)}{\partial \omega_{j,k}} \\
&=& -2(y_k - a_k)g'(in_k)\frac{\partial in_k}{\partial \omega_{j,k}} = -2(y_k - a_k)g'(in_k)\frac{\partial }{\partial \omega_{j,k}}\left( \sum _{j} \omega_{j,k}a_j\right) \\
&=& -\color{red}{2}(y_k - a_k) g'(in_k) a_j = -a_j\Delta_k
\end{eqnarray}

where

$$
\Delta_k = Err_k \times g'(in_k)
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: How is the quantity $Err_k$ defined?

Comment: 'Errk be the kth component of the error vector y − hw':

So Errk is the same as (yk - ak)